# CSS: How to ignore an element so parent's padding will accommodate to other elements?

Tags: css

Here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/53eP6/
[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="small">small text</span>
    <div class="big">Big elements to be ignored</div>
</div>
```

The right element is the one I want to ignore ( in real-life experience, this might be some irregular size imgs)

So the parent element will have a fix height (by its padding and children's height ), rather than expand to fit the height of the big element that I want to ignore.

Comment: What do you mean by *ignore*? Does the `container` and `big` element need to be a fixed size or something, and overlap the smaller one?

Comment: is floating an option? asuming you're trying to align them to top: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/eg7DW/1/

Comment: @Varinder I think float would be a good solution. And I really need to align them to the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply floating the element would be ideal as it will still retain padding information from the parent to align top part correctly with the sibling inline element.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/eg7DW/1/

**Edit**

fixed height on `.container` element

```
.container{
    padding: 10px; 
    background:green;
    height:20px
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/eg7DW/3/

Comment: But got a problem of this. I need the left element's marigin-right to position the big img. (That is, the `.big` is in right side 30px from the left element).

Comment: True, How much control do you have over ```.container``` element? are you allowed to give it a fixed width?

Comment: Maybe not. Its width may just be 100%.

Comment: How about a fixed height on ```.container``` ? that will solve all problems - fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/eg7DW/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
position: relative;
display: inline;
}

.big {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e3vMn/

Comment: What does `left: 100%` mean?

Comment: Check out the fiddle link -- it positions `.big` at 100% (the full width of `.container`) essentially at the right border of `.container`

Comment: But...We're setting the `.container` to `inline`!?

Comment: What if I want an additioanl `float: right` element?  Then the big div would stand out of the `.container` horizontally, rather than staying within it.